# Forbid users to subscribe to Firebase topics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I eliminate the opportunity of an app user to call `FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(String)` in order to handle topic management only server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging topics are public. There is no way to prevent specific users from subscribing to them.

Comment: What do you mean topics are public ? If there are two android projects com.foo.bar and com.buzz.bam; can com.buzz.bam access topics from com.foo.bar ?

Comment: Topics are unique to each app, but they are public to each user of that app. Any user of your app can subscribe to any topic in that app.