# Restricting FCM topic subscription based on APK signing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, signing

I have an Android app that subscribes to a FCM topic named ("alert")....

I only want the signed,published version of my app  Google Play Store to receive messages from the "alert" topic. I do not want an unsigned/debug APK a developer creates with the same package name to be able to subscribe to the topic an receive notifications, even if the unsigned/debug version has the google-services.json configuration. Is it possible to configure the FCM topic to restrict access to only my published app from Google Play Store?

I thought this was possible by configuring the API KEY used in the app from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, and specifying the key restriction to Android apps, and specify a package name and SHA1 from my signing certificate I used for the app...But it seems like even if I do this, an unsigned/debug version of my app still is able to successfully subscribe to the topic and receive messages.

Comment: Sounds interesting, can we know why?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to prevent someone from creating an imposter app with the same package name, sideloaded onto their android device, to receive messages on my topic.

Comment: You have to add the comment explaining your imposter app experiment in the question, and you should send a support request

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to restrict users to subscribe to a topic.

[FCM topics are public. There is no way to prevent specific users from subscribing to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616143/4625829) -- in this case, users or app versions. So long as they are authorized to make a request and know the name of the topic, they could easily subscribe.

Comment: Thanks AL. What do you mean by "so long as they are authorized"? is there a way to make a client app "unauthorized"?

I trying to solve the following" I have an application with a package name com.foo.bar that publishes a message to topic "alert"... I really only want my signed app, with package com.foo.bar downloaded from the app store to be able to subscribe and receive messages....

I don't want an imposter app someone  with com.foo.bar package name, and write code to subscribe to the topic "alert" to be able to sideload the app and receive topic messages.

Comment: From my experimentation, it appears that subscribing to a topic doesn't even require an API KEY. When I changed my test "imposter" app, I changed the API in the google-services.json to something bogus, and I was still able to receive topic notifications. All I needed to do was have an app that was the same package name as my real app, and know the name of the topic. The imposter app wasn't even signed: I adb installed it from Android Studio...

Comment: Hi @FrankL. What I meant by *authorized* was that if the request to subscribe contains the Server Key (if not coming from the client app). Like I mentioned, there is no way to make such restrictions since topics were meant to be public in the first place.

Comment: Another workaround for this is to prefix your topic name with something that only you (and some other trustworthy developers) would know. (e.g. `<code of some sort>-alert`)

Comment: Subscriptions appear to be device based, not user based.